# Endswith and Replacement Syntax - Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm using python pandas to manipulate current columns STY and size (both which are object datatypes). What I want is to remove sty that ends with 'X' and concatanate SIZ + X

Please see the following example below: the top is what i have now, bottom is the result I want (How do I get the result I want?)

[image]

This is my current code:

```
#for removing style 
def reformat(): 
    for n in df['STY']: 
        if str(n).endswith('X') : 
            x = str(n).replace('X','')
#for adding string 'X' 
for x in df['SIZ']: 
    if str(n) in df['STY'].endswith('X'): 
           str(n).join('X')
```

in the end, I want to be able to apply the change and download it in excel.

Comment: @DYZ I just made a slight edit to this, basically on the screenshot i provided, how do i get the result that is shown on the bottom half of the screenshot

Comment: First, do not paste screenshots of your data as they cannot be copied. Paste the actual data. Do all strings in the first column end with X?

Comment: not all strings, this is just an example

Comment: Please provide a more realistic example.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem, as described, can be solved with two statements. The first adds an "X" to the items in the second column if the items in the first column end with an "X":

```
df.loc[df.STY.str.endswith("X"), "SIZ"] += "X"
```

The second removes "X" from the ends of the items in the first column:

```
df.STY.replace("X$", "", regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. The `df.at` call allows an in-place update of the dataframe at a specified location.

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    sty = str(row['STY'])
    siz = str(row['SIZ'])
    if sty.endswith('X'):
        df.at[i, 'STY'] = sty[:-1]  # remove last character from STY
        df.at[i, 'SIZ'] = siz + 'X'  # udpate SIZ to include an X
```

Edit: to save it as excel, do this

```py
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

**UPDATE**

While this solution will work just fine, [DYZ's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61786070/7253453) is far more efficient.

Comment: @DYZ - please clarify your statement with the reason why is it *never* a good solution. Otherwise you're speaking to the wind.

Comment: @BobsBurgers I will give this a go, the issues i've always had is joining strings that has mixed integers and string. hopefully this works thank you

Comment: Pandas Dataframes are designed for vectorized operations on columns, not on individual items.

Comment: @DYZ - ah, so it's a matter of efficiency. Using `iterrows` and `at` will work, but won't be as efficient as your solution. Thanks for the clarification!